How can I hold ownership of something and call a method on it that moves the object?
I have the following code, which wont compile because the call to "self.client.dispose()" moves the object 'client' due to dispose having this signature: dispose(self). Is there anyway around this? I want to dispose of the client so I can create a new one and assign it back to the self.client field. Client is not Copy or Clone - it's a real PITA bit of third party code that I cannot alter.
// third party crate
struct Client { ... }
impl Client {
   async fn dispose(self) -> Result<..> {...}
}

// My code starts here 

struct MyStruct {
  client: Client
}

impl MyStruct {
  async fn do_something(&mut self) -> Result<...> {
     // stuff
     let thing = self.client.create();
     match thing {
        ...
        Err(error) => {
          // recover here by recreating the client, first disposing it
          self.client.dispose().await?; <--- not possible, client is moved

          self.client = Client::new(); // somehow mutate self with new Client
        }
     }
  } 
}

I've tried making the client field a Cell, RefCell, Arc, Mutex, Box of Client. I think if someone could please very kindly rewrite this for me so it's possible to dispose of the client and create a new one to mutate self.client with, I can then try to learn from it.
Many thanks.

This question is similar to: replace a value behind a mutable reference by moving and mapping the original. Your example can use std::mem::replace like in that question, but if you must dispose before Client::new, then you can use the replace_with crate like the answer mentions.

Surely it's possible to do something so basic in Rust without the aid of a third party crate?

std::mem::replace should work for you just fine, no? Or even simpler with std::mem::take if Client implements Default

I tried replace_with and it lets my code compile, so thank you. I'll look at std::mem::replace too, so I don't have to have yet another dependency in this project. I'm not an expert by any means, my apologies if I don't immediately understand how std::mem::replace works.

Ah actually slight snag - i will update the question - i failed to mention that the dispose method is async.

I disagree that this is a duplicate - the similar question is anything but - it doesn't offer any help with the fact that the 'client' cannot be disposed because it moves it, and the dispose call can't be made inside of something like replace_with because it's async.

If the value you are replacing with doesn't depend on owning the previous value, just use std::mem::replace (or std::mem::take if it implements Default).
let prev_client = std::mem::replace(&mut self.client, Client::new());

// You now have the `Client` that was previously in `self` but has been replaced
// with a different value. You can now do whatever you like with it, prev_client
// is the owner now.
prev_client.dispose().await?;

